# How the optical cd disc gets drawn in when we gently push it? what is the mechanism behind it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

We have seen CD drives that have slits. The CD gets drawn inside upon a gentle
push. how the CD gets drawn inside upon a gentle push? How it's mechanism works?
[image: optical CD disc]

Comment: This will be best answered by a youtube video, rather than a text-based answer, I think? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi3v7X6BpAA

Comment: Watch out for the little wheel on an arm at the bottom right

Comment: @Jonathan R swift, Thanks a lot sir

Comment: Interesting. It never occured to me it would grab the disc from the edge. I always figured it was roller wheels on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 3):

These drives are called slot loading optical drives. The mechanical arm grabs the disc and draws into the drive. Below is an image that shows the mechanical grab arm.

[image]

Take a look at [Clear Slot Loading Drive Mod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhvNKMykJfA)

Below are some references that might be helpful

- [Slim Slot-In DVD Drive Mechanism - How does it work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi3v7X6BpAA)
- [Slot loading optical disc drive](https://www.discwizards.com/comparing-optical-drive-loading-mechanisms.htm)

Comment: You might want to mention it's the little wheel on the bottom right, and it only grabs the disc by moving sideways which means it only grabs the disc after it has been pushed in past the halfway point where the diameter starts decreasing so a sideways push brings the disc inward instead of outward. or make a GIF!

Comment: @DKNguyen, This is your contribution. I would encourage you to post an additional response pointing to above comments.